# Run an emulator without camera

Tags: java, android, camera, android-manifest, emulation

I want to emulate an android device that has no in-built camera but I can't find a way to do this. 
I have disabled the options for camera in the Android AVD Manager when creating a new emulator (and hardware), but the resulting emulator still has camera capabilities. I also tried using Genymotion emulator, but that doesn't even seem to have the option to disable camera.

Reason why:
I have this line in my manifest `android:name="android.hardware.camera"` that prevents a user that owns a device without camera from installing my app (Device not compatible). I want to add `android:required="false"` to it but that would mean I also have to implement some code for the case where the user accesses a camera function from my app while not having one on his device, and I need to test that.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Emulator or virtual devices are rooted devices.  So check the installed device was rooted or not. If it was rooted assume that the device didn't have the camera and don't allow to open the camera. ` if (CommonUtils.isRooted(this) || RootShell.isRootAvailable())`  this line of code help to find the installed device is rooted or not.

Comment: The emulator may still have camera capabilities, but fail to open the camera device if you set both front and back to 'None'

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch `Camera` options `Front` and `Back` to `None` in device advanced settings.